# Proving simplification of summation

Tags: summation

I'm trying to prove that $\frac{1}{1+z^2}=1-z^2+z^4-z^6+...$ for $|z|<1$.  The only thing that I can think of is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^{2n}=1-z^2+z^4-z^6+...$, but I'm rather lost.  Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: This is one line away from the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^{2n}$$ is the correct way to write it. But the next thing you should note is the geometric series formula: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac1{1-z}$$
If you substitute $(iz)^2$ into the second equation, you reach 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(iz)^{2n}=\frac1{1-(iz)^2}$$
And since $i^2=-1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^{2n}=\frac1{1+z^2}$$
QED

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(1-y)\sum_{j=0}^ny^j=1-y^{n+1}.$

Let $y=-z^2.$

Comment: Reference topic: Geometric series.